# spring security restful interface - improve json request so as not to pass plaintext password

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring mvc 3.0 webapp which uses spring security. I have implemented a basic json service into the spring security login service but as far as I'm concerned it is not sure enough.

At the moment in my json request I am passing the following type in plain text.

```
{"j_username":"myPlainTextUsername", "j_password":"myPlainTextPassword" , "j_store":"1"}
```

All my passwords are stored in the database using a straight md5 encryption. My application uses the following spring config.

```
<beans:bean id="userDetailsDao" 
    class="com.mycompany.reporting.dao.UserDetailsDaoImpl"/>

<beans:bean id="encoder" 
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" 
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider"
    p:userDetailsService-ref="userDetailsDao"
    p:passwordEncoder-ref="encoder" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="false">
    <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"></authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Instead of putting the plaintext password in the json request I would like to try and improve this by including a string which is an md5 hash of...

> 1. The username (salt)
> 2. the url (salt)
> 3. the password

Then I want to be able to decrypt, separate the salt from the password and then authenticate. I know spring security allows for salt but I think that is only useful when the passwords are stored with salt in the db.

Can someone help me with suggestions on how to do this? Is there anything in spring that can help me with what I want to do?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, md5 is not inversible. So if you get an md5 hash of the password, you can only compare it to the md5 hash stored in your database. And the comparison will only have sense if both hashes use same salt.

If it is an option, it would be simpler to use https for the login page and keep on sending password as clear text - but through a https encrypted channel.

If not, you will have to store the password as plain text (or with a reversible encoding which looks better but does not really increase security) in your database to be able to do same hashing on both sides and compare hash values.

Comment: Thks for feedback but If md5 is not reversible how do those sites on the internet decrypt an md5 string into clear text?

Comment: Also, I don't know much about https but if I change my spring security authentication to use it will that mean when I send a json request to my authentication module with a password in clear text that it is secure? Ie no one can sniff the password

Comment: @Richie : Sites do not decrypt the md5 string. They encode the clear text string and compare it to the md5 one. For the security, except if there is a flaw in implementation, no one can sniff https traffic (it is one of the reasons for https). And you have nothing to change in auth config, but simply add a `requires-channel=https` attribute on an `<intercept-url>` element.

Comment: thanks for your help and advice. I will have a play and see what i can do